# hover over a:nth-child(5) and (7) to effect a:nth-child(8)

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why im finding this soo difficult.. I'm trying to make it so when you hover over RBA **and** RDA it also underlines to word "atomizer" at the end.

Am I not targeting them correctly?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c98nx905/1/)**

**HTML/CSS**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700italic,700,500italic,400italic,300italic,300);
 #heroLinks-Wrap {
  width: 692px;
  height: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #7777ff;
  font-size: 26.5px;
  letter-spacing: .7200002px;
}
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(1n+1) {
  color: #4e4eff;
}
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(1n+1):hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(8):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(5):hover + #heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(8) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="heroLinks-Wrap">
  <a>Mechanical Mods</a>  <span>•</span>  <a>Glass Caps</a>  <span>•</span>  <a>RBA</a>  <span>&#38;</span>  <a>RDA</a>  <a>Atomizers</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9j782tht/

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much! Please format it as an answer and post it and I will choose it as the answer. 

Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `a:nth-child(5):hover + #heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(8)`, isn't selecting anything due to the fact that the element `#heroLinks-Wrap` is not an adjacent sibling with the anchor element.

In other words, when selecting adjacent sibling elements using `+`, the following selector doesn't start selecting from the root again (which means that you don't need to specify the parent element again).

Therefore you can omit `#heroLinks-Wrap` from the second part of the selector and then replace the adjacent sibling combinator, `+`, with the general sibling combinator, `~` (since the elements aren't always adjacent siblings):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dfgos5a7/)

```
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(5):hover ~ a:nth-child(8),
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-child(7):hover ~ a:nth-child(8) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

---

It's also worth mentioning that the [`:nth-of-type()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) may be a better fit since you are only targeting anchor elements:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1b6vr4ca/)

```
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ a:nth-of-type(5),
#heroLinks-Wrap a:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ a:nth-of-type(5) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```